# _gfxFreeTextureLevel crash

Tags: ios, opengl-es, crash, render

0
libsystem_kernel.dylib
___pthread_kill + 8

1
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_kill + 208

2
libsystem_c.dylib
_abort + 124

3
libGFXShared.dylib
_gfxFreeTextureLevel

4
GLEngine
_gleGenMipmaps + 332

5
GLEngine
_gleGenerateMipmap + 244

6
GLEngine
_glGenerateMipmapEXT_Exec + 768

7
BlockModsGameKit
LORD::GLES2Texture::create2DRespond(LORD::GLES2Texture::Texture2D const&) + 616

8
BlockModsGameKit
LORD::GLES2Texture::_upload_common() + 200

I encountered this crash on the iOS app. Does anyone know why? I searched for a long time but couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.